# Escape forward slash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to escape forward slashes from an URL like this

```
"http://example.com/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd" => "http:\/\/example.com\/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd"
```

But when I try with gsub, this is what I'm getting

```
"http://example.com/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd".gsub("/", '\/')
=> "http:\\/\\/example.com\\/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd"
```

I also tried with

```
"http://example.com/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd".gsub("/", '/' => '\/')
```

and

```
"http://example.com/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd".gsub(/[\/]/, '\/')
```

with the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to escape forward slashes?

Comment: **Why**? This sounds like a textbook [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to active here?

Comment: For what it's worth, your very first attempt (`.gsub("/", '\/')`) already solves the problem you are asking. The "double back-slash" you are seeing is just a way of displaying "this is a literal backslash character, rather than the next character being escaped".

Comment: Ruby is doing the right thing. The `\` character is a special character in ruby, so it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @DaveNewton this is for a custom app that expects the strings with the forward slashes escaped that way.

Comment: This is a classic "how many backslashes do you need" problem.  It's like writing a program in Korn shell, using the ECHO builtin, to generate a C program that includes printf format strings.  Does this backslash turn into four backslashes, or eight, or, for that matter, sixteen? ;-)  You must understand the semantics of elision PRECISELY before tackling this task.

Comment: That custom app sounds broken, but in any case you've already solved it, you just don't realize it.

Comment: Further to @Tom's point, `puts "http://example.com/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd".gsub("/", '\/')` prints `http:\/\/example.com\/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd`, showing it is escaped correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the interactive ruby shell you're using is adding extra backslashes that aren't really there.

I tried your code in `irb` and got the same result:

```
irb(main):005:0> "http://example.com/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd".gsub("/", '\/')
"http:\\/\\/example.com\\/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd"
```

But if I use `puts()` it prints correctly:

```
irb(main):006:0> puts "http://example.com/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd".gsub('/', '\/')
http:\/\/example.com\/qb-xhtml-v1.xsd
=> nil
```

I suspect that the ruby shell is simply escaping the backslashes for convenience, which is causing confusion.

Comment: It's not convenience, it's because Ruby strings expressed in their string literal format require escaping on special characters, and backslash is one of those.